# Visual Studio Error display

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can the errors in Visual Studio be displayed as in this image:

[image]

instead of using the Error List?

The exceptions I get are displayed like this:

[image]

(The images are from: [How to tell the debugger to ignore breaking on thrown exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499473/how-to-tell-the-debugger-to-ignore-breaking-on-thrown-exceptions#comment26280670_4499473), [Where did my Visual Studio exception assistant go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426856/where-did-my-visual-studio-exception-assistant-go))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where did my Visual Studio exception assistant go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426856/where-did-my-visual-studio-exception-assistant-go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look under Tools | Options in the Debugging | General node, be sure your "Enable the Exception Assistant" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that is displayed in the first picture is a message displayed for .Net exceptions. (Anything that inherits from `System.Exception`)

The .Net exception class has members that include data and stack trace that can be displayed nicely and the Visual Studio IDE displayes it for you.

Native errors (from native code or windows code, anything not .Net) is displayed with the second window.

Native exceptions to contain a minimal `what()` string. Sometimes. But any other class type can be thrown too, so there's not always that much information.